# LED MOSFET switching circuit

Tags: arduino, led, diodes

So here's my circuit for powering 4 LEDs with my arduino. Right now it seems to be working perfectly. I send HIGH to any of the pins and it lights the LED. I was wondering if I take in account the voltage drop, if any, across the MOSFET when calculating the current limiting resistor value. Right now I just calculate \$\frac{V_S-V_{LED}}{I_{LED}}\$.

Also, do I need any pull up resistor or anything to increase its efficiency or reliability?

I'm using a BS170 N MOSFET

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BS/BS170.pdf) is your friend.

Assuming you are using an Arduino Uno with 5V outputs, when a GPIO pin is high, \$V_{GS} = \$ 5V. Your drain current \$I_D\$ is the same as the current through an LED, so you set this to your desired forward current. Let's say \$I_D = I_{LED} = \$ 5mA.

We now know that \$V_{GS}\$ = 5V and \$I_D = \$ 5mA. Figure 2 of the datasheet provides a nominal \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ at a given gate voltage and drain current. For \$V_{GS}\$ = 5V, \$I_D = \$ 5mA, the figure shows just a tad below 1.5Ω. Knowing this, we can approximate \$V_{DS} = R_{DS} * I_D \simeq \$ 7.5mV. This is small enough to neglect. Keep in mind that the datasheet values are nominal, and your MOSFET may vary quite a bit. Luckily, even if \$R_{DS}\$ varies by a factor of 10, it will still be negligible for your application!

In general, assuming you have a chosen an appropriate MOSFET (and are therefore operating with a \$V_{GS} > V_{GS(th)}\$ and you have selected said MOSFET so that its nominal \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ is small (higher current implies a smaller needed \$R_{DS(ON)}\$), the \$V_{DS}\$ of the MOSFET when it is on should be negligible. In other words, you should select a MOSFET such that you *don't* need to factor it into your current-limiting resistor equation.

> Also, do I need any pull up resistor or anything to increase its efficiency or reliability?

Your Arduino GPIO pin will drive the gate both high and low, so no, a pullup/pulldown isn't necessary (as long as your Arduino will always be connected to the MOSFETs and driving them). However, it is good practice to put a gate resistor between the Arduino and each MOSFET gate. In this application, it's not crucial, but a gate resistor controls ringing at the gate. 100Ω or so is fine (the value isn't crucial).

If the Arduino isn't always connected, then a pulldown resistor is appropriate (to prevent the gates from floating). 1MΩ to ground is sufficient. Again, the value isn't particularly crucial, any large resistor is fine.

Comment: Okay thanks so are you saying this MOSFET is okay for my situation or should i find a different one?

Comment: You didn't state how much current you were running through your LEDs. But assuming the current is sub 100mA, you'll be fine. Past that, do the math and see e.g. at 400mA, you'll see ~0.64V across the MOSFET.

Comment: Ah okay thanks sorry! The LEDS take 30mA, 30mA, 50mA, and 100mA so I should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have a minimal if any drop across the source drain junction. The resistance should be under 1 ohm, and the voltage should be a fraction of a volt. But it depends on the current you are passing through it. The datasheet will show the Rds when on.

You should be pretty close to your target Vf and If if you ignore it, but you could measure the drop across, and current through the mosfet when on,  then recalculate.

Comment: Yeah so tomorrow I plan on measuring the current when the mosfet is on to see what it is. thanks!